# R: parsing data into a table after webscraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am able to webscrape some data but I am  having problems formatting it in a table containing four columns, empty column, three columns.

```
library("methods")
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.galmarley.com/prices/CSV/AUX/USD/600/Full")
page
sources <- page %>%html_text()
as.data.frame(sources)
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the object `source` ended up as a character string, but fortunately it is well formatted. In this case, `read.table` works well to put it into a single dataframe. Then you can use `stringr::str_split_fixed` to split on the comma which separates the columns.

```
library(stringr)
df <- read.table(text = sources, sep = "\n")
df <- str_split_fixed(df$V1, pattern = ",", 9)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

the website you have is really not a page, its a document. Just add `.csv` at the end and read the data in:

```
  read.csv("https://www.galmarley.com/prices/CSV/AUX/USD/600/Full.csv")
```

or you can read directly what you have:

```
 read.csv(text=sources)
```